# Tabs that switch multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I really stuck on this, what I need is to switch the image together with the tabs text, but the image should be outside of the tabs container. I made some jQuery code, but it's not flexible in case if I want to add more tabs and the functions are duplicating, which is also looks not so well.

Is there some option, maybe a function that will check if the number of cliked tab will match with image id and switch the image according this number.

Please help :)
The code example - http://codepen.io/DeoThemes/pen/EyAjVA

**jQuery:**

```
$('#tabs-img-1').show();

$("a[href='#tab-1']").on('click', function() {    
    $('.tabs-img').hide();
    $('#tabs-img-1').show();
});

$("a[href='#tab-2']").on('click', function() {
    $('.tabs-img').hide();
    $('#tabs-img-2').show();
});

$("a[href='#tab-3']").on('click', function() {
  $('.tabs-img').hide();
  $('#tabs-img-3').show();
});

$("a[href='#tab-4']").on('click', function() {
  $('.tabs-img').hide();
  $('#tabs-img-4').show();
});

$("a[href='#tab-5']").on('click', function() {
  $('.tabs-img').hide();
  $('#tabs-img-5').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do without changing any of your code. Let me know your feedback. Thanks!

```
$('.tabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function() {
  $('.tabs-img').hide();
  $('#tabs-img-' + $(this).attr('href').split('-')[1]).show();
});
```

or better still you can place an attribute on the `a` tag which will be the id of the tab!

Comment: Thanks, that's actually work :) Can you explain what [1] means? jQuery will use the number increasing by 1?

Comment: I `split` the href of the `a` tag- for instance `tab-3` by the character `-` and select the element at index `1` which is `3` in this case...

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your [Codepen](http://codepen.io/ekhmoi/pen/pbGJAk).

Add custom attribute to anchor link:

```
<a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab" imgId="#tabs-img-1">Business Oriented</a>
```

And then change your script to this:

```
$("ul.nav-tabs li a").on('click', function() {     
    $('.tabs-img').hide();
    $($(this).attr('imgId')).show();    
});
```